# How to collect shpfiles from "Iterate Feature Classes" into SINGLE input to "Intersect" tool?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder

Need to collect output files (Iterate Feature Classes) into single input to INTERSECT tool.

Collect values isnt working (wrong data type)!

Only precondition is available (see pic):

http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/2945/54132406.png

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this using Append instead of Intersect (because I don't have Advanced license to do more than two input feature classes), but otherwise my model was the same and it worked.  It was actually the first time I had used Collect Values which I was keen to test.

The difference between your model and mine was that there was no connection between FeatureClass and Intersect/Append.  Delete that connection and then you should be able to add a connection from Output Values to Intersect that is not a precondition.

## UPDATE

This appears to be bug number [NIM052331](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDUyMzMx) which currently has a status of Declined - if this is affecting you the best course of action may be to report it to your local Esri support.  A workaround would be to use Python/ArcPy rather than ModelBuilder to do this.

Comment: http://img815.imageshack.us/img815/6974/76807390.png 


Isnt working see discription for "collect values" 
 http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000005000000.htm 
its says:  
The Collect Values tool is designed to collect output values of an iterator or to convert a list of multivalues into a single input. The output of Collect Values can be used as input to tools like Merge, Append, Mosaic, and Cell Statistics.

Comment: I was hoping that Intersect was enough like the other tools for it to work just like them, but it looks like the input grid for it is expecting a list with feature class and rank pairs whereas Append just wants a list of feature classes.  I'd say that this is the issue Declined for attention in NIM052331 (http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDUyMzMx) and that you may want to take it up with your local support.

Comment: thx for your help